CocoaPods Error: Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
I am encountering an issue while trying to run pod install for my Flutter project on an iPhone 15 Pro simulator. The error message indicates a problem with Unicode Normalization for ASCII-8BIT encoding. Below is the short error log:
For Full Logs -> https://pastebin.com/LxUXZxTw
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

/Users/chandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Users/chandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Users/chandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `installation_root'
    from /Users/chandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:227:in `podfile_path'



It's Pritty simple to fix this error:
Just follow these 3 steps.
STEP-1: open you fresh terminal and run this command open ~/.zshrc

STEP-2: In .zshrc file in last line paste this export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and save.

STEP-3: open Android Studio goto files -> Invalidate caches... -> select all options -> and click invalidate and restart.


